# Update a data property is not working on button click in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi i am getting data for year 2018 on page load that is working.
If i select a different year and click update the value for the 2019 is not updating in my application.

It seems the vue is not rendering properly. Is there any way to render this.

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dispData: {}
  },
  methods: {
    // this selYr will be passed as 2019 on button click
    initReport: function(selYr) {
      if (selYr == 2019) {
        this.dispData = JSON.parse(table_Data.getPageData2019);
      }
      else {
        this.dispData = JSON.parse(table_Data.getPageData2018); 
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: How are you invoking `initReport` in your code? Are you sure `selYr` is being passed in as a number? Please create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example in your question.

Comment: yeah, even i have tried hardcoding the value still the instance is not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is json data and the values are not bound, you may have to use [`vm.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) to update the data.

e.g:

```
vm.$set(this,'dispData',JSON.parse(table_Data.getPageData2019));
```

Comment: Hi  Andy, thanks for the reply, i have tried the above still the issue exists. is there any other option ?

Comment: Hi @Mani079, as far as i can see it should work, the problem may be with your data. i made a fiddle here with example data which seems to be updating correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/mvbjnewx/2/

Comment: Andy in my case, on the method i am able to get the response json data, but the setting to the dispData is not being rendered, i have tried with writing the data in the page the data is not being changed or rendered it seems. know any reason  why. And i am using the same button to pass the years, it will not be an issue right ?

Comment: Hi @Mani079, i don't know how you loaded your data, is it loaded already or is it loading on the spot? Have you tried to use a console.log to see if the data is returned? Have you tried with fake data to see if this works?

Comment: i am trying to load data on button click, i have tried with both alert and console.log. both of them are showing the updated data. The only problem is it is not being rendered into webpage

Comment: Hi Andy, one more thing, after the button click if i navigate to a different component and then came back the data is being updated properly. is there any way to make that progrmmatically without going and coming back from a different component

Answer (score -1):

After receiving @terry feedback, I realize this is not relevant, I've spun up a simple example working with data. Perhaps try to plug your data into it and see if it works?

https://codesandbox.io/s/ry194p818o

Comment: You do not need to use data as a function when you're dealing with an app. You only do that for components, when there is a chance of having multiple instances of it.

Comment: your code is working but i need to do it on a single button click

Comment: Ok, attach the method in my code linked to a button click, it should still work.

Comment: i too can able to get the updated value in console.log and alert commands. the data is not being rendered in the webpage only